# Как настроить почту через smtp yandex на CentOS 7?

Tags: centos7

Почта настроена и работает по [этой инструкции](https://www.kost.su/postfix-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-smtp-yandex/), но письма приходят с содержанием следующей строки "root".

Как изменить строку root?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нажав [edit], замените приложенную картинку, ни о чём не говорящую, на полное содержимое письма. ну, хотя бы заголовков. хотя бы тех, что содержат слово `root`. реальные доменные имена/ip-адреса можете заменить на произвольные значения.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin думаю картинка тут уместна, но то что кода нет, это согласен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вообще, конечно, надо соответствующим образом настроить ту программу, которая формирует письмо (чтобы она вписывала то, что вам нужно, в заголовок `from`).

если это проблематично, можно исправить в настройках следующей в цепочке программы, [*mta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent). смотрите в документации к той реализации, которую вы используете.

---

ну и как запасной универсальный обходной вариант, можете вписать нужное в четвёртое поле в `/etc/passwd` для пользователя *root* (только латиницей и без `:`).

т.е., если было примерно так:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

то сделайте примерно так

```
root:x:0:0:immortalis te salutant:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Через postfix отправляется, где только не писал, не получается исправить.

Comment: Есть ещё одна проблема, как видно из скриншота, после слова Test идёт кириллица слово "сообщения", и отсутствует пробел, в команде пробел присутствует — echo "Hello world" | mail -s "Test сообщения from Yandex Relay" eu..rov@gmail.com почему возникает такая ошибка?

Comment: вероятно потому, что символы, не входящие в ascii, должны быть закодированы в соответствии с [rfc2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt)